# Webscraping the links from a table

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, data-science

I want to web scrape the links and their respective texts from a table. I plan to use regex to accomplish this.

So let's say in this page I have multiple `<a href="url_i">text_i</a>` tags. I want to get all the text_i's into a list and then get all the href's into a separate list.

I have:

```
web = requests.get(url)
web_text = web.text
texts = re.findall(r'<table .*><a .*>(.*)</a></table>, web_text)'
```

The regex expression finds all the anchor tags, of whatever class, inside a HTML table of whatever class and returns the texts, correct? This is taking an extraordinarily long time. Is this the correct way to do it?

Also, how do I go about getting the href url's now?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to parse the HTML text of the table.

Adapted from [Beautiful Soup's documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) you could do for example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(web_text, 'html.parser')

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```